# corda-webserver connect to p2pAddress of corda node

Tags: corda

We tried to start up corda-webserver to connect to existing corda node but encountered following error message. 
corda-webserver.jar, corda.jar, and node.conf are in the folder. Would you please help us? Thank you.

```
[ERROR] 2017-12-13T09:32:48,957Z [main] core.client.createConnection - AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
[INFO ] 2017-12-13T09:32:48,959Z [main] internal.RPCClient.logElapsedTime - Startup took 10010 msec
[INFO ] 2017-12-13T09:32:49,960Z [main] internal.NodeWebServer.connectLocalRpcAsNodeUser - Connecting to node at 1.115.29.253:**10002** as node user
```

Corda version : 1.0

node.conf

```
myLegalName="O=XXX,L=XXXX,C=XX"
networkMapService {
    address="one-networkmap.corda.r3cev.com:10002"
    legalName="L=Dublin, C=IE, O=TestNet NetworkMap"
}
p2pAddress="1.115.29.253:10002"
rpcAddress="1.115.29.253:10003"
webAddress="1.115.29.253:10004"
keyStorePassword : "XXX"
trustStorePassword : "XXX"
extraAdvertisedServiceIds: [ "" ]
useHTTPS : false
devMode : false
rpcUsers=[
    {
        user=XXX
        password=XXX
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
    }
]
certificateSigningService="https://one-doorman.corda.r3cev.com"
```

full log of corda-webserver

```
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:08,523Z [main] webserver.CmdLineOptions.loadConfig - Config:
{
    # hardcoded value
    "baseDirectory" : "/home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA",
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 23
    "certificateSigningService" : "https://one-doorman.corda.r3cev.com",
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 13
    "devMode" : false,
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 11
    "extraAdvertisedServiceIds" : [
        # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 11
        ""
    ],
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 9
    "keyStorePassword" : "cordacadevpass",
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 1
    "myLegalName" : "O=XXX,L=XXXX,C=XX",
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 2
    "networkMapService" : {
        # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 3
        "address" : "one-networkmap.corda.r3cev.com:10002",
        # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 4
        "legalName" : "L=Dublin, C=IE, O=TestNet NetworkMap"
    },
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 6
    "p2pAddress" : "1.115.29.253:10002",
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 7
    "rpcAddress" : "1.115.29.253:10003",
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 14
    "rpcUsers" : [
        # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 15
        {
            # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 17
            "password" : "corda_is_awesome",
            # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 18
            "permissions" : [
                # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 19
                "ALL"
            ],
            # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 16
            "user" : "corda"
        }
    ],
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 10
    "trustStorePassword" : "trustpass",
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 12
    "useHTTPS" : false,
    # /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/node.conf: 8
    "webAddress" : "1.115.29.253:10004"
}

[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:08,547Z [main] Main.main - Main class: /home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/corda-webserver-impl-1.0.0.jar
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:08,579Z [main] Main.main - CommandLine Args: -Xmx200m -XX:+UseG1GC -javaagent:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar -Dvisualvm.display.name=Corda -Djava.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0 -Dcapsule.app=net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0 -DWebserver -Dcapsule.dir=/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0 -Dcapsule.jar=/home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/corda-webserver.jar
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:08,670Z [main] Main.main - Application Args: 
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:08,670Z [main] Main.main - bootclasspath: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/classes
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:08,670Z [main] Main.main - classpath: /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/corda-webserver.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/corda-rpc-1.0.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/corda-jackson-1.0.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/corda-node-api-1.0.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/corda-core-1.0.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jetty-webapp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jersey-container-jetty-http-2.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jetty-security-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/log4j-core-2.7.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jersey-server-2.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/kotlinx-html-jvm-0.6.3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.1.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jackson-module-kotlin-2.8.5.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/kotlin-reflect-1.1.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jsr305-3.0.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/rxjava-1.2.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/commons-jexl3-3.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.8.5.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/eddsa-0.2.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.57.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/bcprov-jdk15on-1.57.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.8.5.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/artemis-commons-2.1.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/guava-21.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jetty-xml-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jolokia-server-detector-2.0.0-M3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jolokia-service-jsr160-2.0.0-M3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jolokia-service-jmx-2.0.0-M3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jolokia-service-serializer-2.0.0-M3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jolokia-service-notif-pull-2.0.0-M3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jolokia-service-notif-sse-2.0.0-M3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jolokia-service-discovery-2.0.0-M3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jolokia-service-history-2.0.0-M3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jolokia-server-core-2.0.0-M3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/commons-io-2.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/log4j-api-2.7.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jersey-client-2.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jersey-media-jaxb-2.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jersey-common-2.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jersey-entity-filtering-2.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b30.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/hk2-api-2.5.0-b30.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/javax.inject-2.5.0-b30.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jetty-http-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jetty-io-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jetty-continuation-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.5.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jackson-core-2.8.5.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/config-1.3.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/kryo-serializers-0.41.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/kryo-4.0.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/proton-j-0.21.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jersey-guava-2.25.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b30.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b30.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jgroups-3.6.13.Final.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/geronimo-json_1.0_spec-1.0-alpha-1.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/johnzon-core-0.9.5.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/reflectasm-1.11.3.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/objenesis-2.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/asm-5.0.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/corda-webserver-impl-1.0.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/plugins/corda-finance-1.0.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/plugins/java-source-0.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA/plugins/tradeix-concord-demo_marcopolo-release-2017-12-06-14-05-12.jar:/home/ubuntu/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_1.0.0/quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:08,671Z [main] Main.main - VM Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:08,671Z [main] Main.main - Machine: ip-10-240-2-174
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:08,672Z [main] Main.main - Working Directory: /home/ubuntu/Corda/r3_Testnet/PartyA
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:09,471Z [main] Main.main - Starting as webserver on 1.115.29.253:10004
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:09,527Z [main] BasicInfo.logAndMaybePrint - Starting as webserver: 1.115.29.253:10004
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:09,527Z [main] internal.NodeWebServer.connectLocalRpcAsNodeUser - Connecting to node at 1.115.29.253:10002 as node user
[ERROR] 2017-12-15T10:29:20,917Z [main] core.client.createConnection - AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:20,967Z [main] internal.RPCClient.logElapsedTime - Startup took 11190 msec
[INFO ] 2017-12-15T10:29:21,968Z [main] internal.NodeWebServer.connectLocalRpcAsNodeUser - Connecting to node at 1.115.29.253:10002 as node user
```

Comment: A couple of things: 1. Is the node running correctly?; 2. Does the webserver work? It appears to indicate connection was successful after that initial error.; 3. Can you update the answer with the relevant section of the node webserver logs (under `logs/web`)?

Comment: 1. yes, the node is running correctly.

Comment: 2. no. webserver is down now.

Comment: 3. update full log of corda-webserver

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect to the node via the RPC port as opposed to the P2P port. Cheers!

Comment: Agree. However, In node.conf, p2pAddress is port "10002" and rpcAddress is "10003", no idea why corda-webserver always connect to "10002" automatically. May I know if any missing configuration in node.conf?

Comment: Hey @NickLiu. The p2p address is for communication between nodes. The RPC address is for connections from RPC clients. The web-address is also specified in the build.gradle - it looks like yours is 10004.

Can you describe your issue in more detail? Does the webserver attempt to connect to 10002 on start up?